# How to back up and trasnfer ubuntu data and application?

Tags: 12.10, backup

Alright, I want to re-install Ubuntu, to give it a bigger partition / fix some stuffs and what not. How do I back up all my data, and applications. Does anyone know of any simple tutorials? I'm not really much of a techie. Do I just copy my `/home` and `/ect` to the new Ubuntu install? 
All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Most recent up to date information about your promlem can be found on the Ubuntu Wiki

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CategoryBackupRecovery